# Changed windows system clock now date modified of files are wrong

Tags: compile, date-time, visual-studio-2013, publishing

I was working in Visual Studio 2013 and testing some code for event handling on specific dates. I changed the Windows clock to be 1/1/2016, compiled code in visual studio (specifically a web project so technically I published) and pushed the files to my dev environment.

After testing I changed my system clock back to the current date and continued coding. Published again and now I notice that some of the files I edited since the last time change are still showing a last modified date of 1/1/2016. Now when I push the changes to dev it doesn't know that the file has been modified and never reflects the changes I've made in the code.

How can I fix the compile so that it compiles using the current and correct date time?

I've tried deleting the folder in which the publish gets pushed to thinking it'd use the current correct system date time but that is still not the case.

Comment: Generally a dangerous thing to change you system date. You might encounter even more issue with your system later. - I would try to 'touch' all those source files so they get the current date. Not sure if Windows has a tool that is equivalent to 'touch' on *nix.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Clean** your solution
2. **Rebuild** the solution
3. **Delete** all the files in the published area
4. **Republish**.

In newer versions of visual studio, there is an option to delete all files as part of the publish process, at least with filesystem publishing.

**Clean** will delete the existing binaries for your source. That should address any files that were built while the system time was altered.

**Rebuild** will recompile all the binaries from scratch. These new files should reflect the current system time. On a side note, avoid using the regular **Build** option, as it will not change files that are newer or unchanged in code since their last compile.

Finally, deleting the published files, and republishing will export the newly built binaries, without any of the old versions with messed up timestamps.

Here is some coverage of the differences between Build, Rebuild, and Clean:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/663453/Understanding-Clean-Build-and-Rebuild-in-Visual-St

Edit: 
These steps will work for most VS project types, but will not work for traditional ASP.Net webforms apps, because aspx files are both source and content from the compilers perspective, so they are not replaced during build.

Comment: Even after cleaning, rebuilding, deleting the deploy folder and then redeploying the files still show a modified date of when I changed my system clock. In another attempt I tried the same steps and also "Rebuilt the web site".

Comment: what files specifically are showing the bad time stamp? are they code files or content?

Comment: About 98% of my `bin` files (code files, `.aspx.cs`) and `.aspx` files in folders which I modified when the time was changed to 1/1/2016.

Comment: ahh, OK, that sucks. There is no good way to fix the ASPX files as they don't get replaced during compile, unless you precompile with non-updatable assemblies, and that will only fix the published output, not the source files themselves. you will have to manually alter each of the files, or use tools like this one, or powershell scripts to fix them: http://dottech.org/104563/windows-review-smart-timestamp/  http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/01/use-powershell-to-modify-file-access-time-stamps.aspx

Comment: I'm not confident that changing the modified time stamp on the deploy files will completely solve my situation. If I change the time stamps on these files now that may solve it temporarily. But if I build again in a few hours then those files may become over written by the build again with the invalid date **again**.

Comment: you change the dates on your solution's files themselves, not the published copies. Delete the published files you have, and republish. then you will not have any files with bad dates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33293/discussion-between-gh0st-and-frank-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio was `Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:`. I deleted the temp location and then re-deployed. When the project was finished redeploying the current date was found in the date modified file attributes.

Comment: glad you got it working. Where is this temp area you discovered?